# Cannot send request to local API from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, localhost

I have an Elixir/Phoenix REST API running on `localhost PORT 4000`.

```
# config/dev.exs

config :mad_api, MadApiWeb.Endpoint,
  # Binding to loopback ipv4 address prevents access from other machines.
  # Change to `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}` to allow access from other machines.
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4000],
  check_origin: false,
  code_reloader: true,
  debug_errors: false,
  secret_key_base: "02+KZVJ+hyW3HFFiingoYebM3aobXLFZOfbE2krkJ5sxhwW/8W+Cr2wPW2Syir1k",
  watchers: []
```

I have a NodeJS (DiscordJS) application on `localhost` as well that needs to send request to that REST API. The REST API does not need any authentication, so a plain `GET` request should work, and it does work both on Postman and browser.

However, I keep getting an `ECONNREFUSED` error.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 4000
}
```

I tried using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici), both producing the same error.

```js
const url = "http://localhost:4000/api/todos/1";

// axios version
const axios = require("axios");
const response = axios.get(url);

// undici version
const { request } = require("undici");
const { body } = await request(url);
```

It looks like the NodeJS app just cannot connect to my local REST API.

Does anyone have a solution?

So far I tried to:

- Change the REST API `PORT` from `4000` to `8000`
- "Change to `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}` to allow access from other machines", in `config/dev.exs`
- `console.log()`ing the url and clicking it, works just fine on browser
- Sending requests to [reqres](https://reqres.in/) and my deployed REST API, both works fine

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

```js
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/todos/1";
```